# Capybara installation

Tags: qt, capybara-webkit

I was following the instruction from article https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Installing-Qt-and-compiling-capybara-webkit for setting up an environment in my research of web automation. I'm using Windows installation case. Everything was perfect untill the point 11. When I type *bundle exec rake build* in my cmd I recieve this:

Command 'qmake CONFIG+\=test' not available.

I've read difficulties are not something unexpected at this step, so may be someone have seen this message before?

Comment: For the Qt libraries I was using installation package named "qt-win-opensource-4.8.5-mingw"

Comment: Update: after studying advices from forums I've reinstalled qt following this link: http://sourceforge.net/projects/qt64ng/files/qt/x86-64/4.8.5/mingw-4.8/qt-4.8.5-x64-mingw481r1.exe/download. Still it had no effect..

Comment: Actually there is not need for QT itself. Capybara will work without QT.

Comment: Capybara-webkit is the capybara driver that uses WebKit via QtWebKit.

Comment: ok. For me it is working fine.. If you need QT, download form here: qt.io & install and set bin folder to path.